# Multiple Box shadows doesn't work in MSEdge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, styling, box-shadow

Adding Multiple box-shadows works partially. While the shadows appear on both the left and right sides of the box in all the browsers, it doesn't appear on the left side in MSEdge.

I have tried adding border-collapse: seperate, display: block and inline-block, background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1) but none of these seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Shadows should appear on the left-side as well in MSEdge.

Comment: I try to test your above code with chrome and MS Edge browser and I got the similar output in both browsers. Here is the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/13D5v67n/223.png Can you please show us, what result you are getting in different browsers may help us to understand the issue in better way. Also let us know, Which version of Edge you are using for making this test?

Comment: I have tried in code-pen and it does show a different result
https://codepen.io/vinodh99/pen/pMadMw

Comment: I have been using browserstack for your reference @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: I try to check your codepen example with Chrome and Edge side by side and I did not see any difference in the result. Here is the Output. https://i.postimg.cc/bJcxPh6g/225.png Still we are not able to produce the issue using your code example. I suggest you to directly try to run the code in browser and do not use Browserstack for testing purpose to see the result. If it works correctly than it can be possible that there is some issue related with your Browserstack.

Comment: Can I know where you have been testing your code? Is there any alternative other than browserstack and virtual box for Mac?

Comment: I am directly running the code in MS Edge browser in Windows 10 OS. For Mac OS you can use the virtual machine to run any Windows OS or you can also try to use new MS Edge Chromium browser. Which is available for Win 7, win 8, win 8.1, win 10 and MAC OS. See here. https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download Note that it is using Chromium browser engine same as chrome browser. Edge HTML is only available on Windows 10.

Comment: Any VM gives me the same result. Running in the new MSEdge chromium is different from actual MSEdge browser as it is powered by another engine. Therefore it is not a good approach to test it there. I have tested in a PC and as you said it works fine. So the issue here is pixel density. The shadow is still there everywhere but it just doesn't appear. The only work around for this problem for now is to change the values. Thanks @Deepak-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with the pixel density in any testing environment (VirtualBox, browserstack, sauce labs etc.). The shadow is still present everywhere but it just doesn't appear in testing environments. Testing in an actual browser gives the desired output. Not sure about what is causing this but it is an issue with the image on any virtual machine.